# 80s/90s alien movie with nuclear power plant

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to remember the name of this movie. There's actually 2. Can't remember the first one either.

1st movie: a team gets sent to what I think is Mexico to deal with an alien creature. They fail so the government sends a fighter to drop a nuke. One guy survives the blast by jumping in a well.

2nd movie: the alien that was killed in movie 1 has a mate. This mate comes for revenge. A team kills it by melting it in a pool of acid at a nuclear power plant

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?

Comment: On TV in the early 2000s. Probably sci-fi channel

Answer (score 9):

This sounds very much like *[Interceptor Force](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167215/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_8_tt_8_nm_0_q_interceptor%2520)* (originally released as just "Interceptors") from 1999, and its low-budget sequel *[Interceptor Force 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0316030/plotsummary/?ref_=tt_ov_pl)*.

The IMDB summary for the first film agrees with the main points in the question. An elite team are sent to Mexico to investigate reports of an alien landing:

> In the near future, the government has created an elite team of
> soldiers specially trained in the event of a hostile alien encounter.
> A multi-national force of the world's best, they are known as the
> Interceptor Force. A covert early warning satellite network tracks an
> object crash landing in a town in the Pacific Northwest. Within
> minutes of the impact, all communication with the town is mysteriously
> severed. The news sources are given a false story of contamination and
> the area is sealed off. AWAC's and fighters patrol the perimeter. As
> the silence from the town continues, the Interceptor team lead by
> Lieutenant Sean Lambert (Gruner) is sent in to investigate. An MC 130
> Talon is scrambled for Lambert and his team to make the high altitude
> air drop. Once inside, the team encounters an alien race capable of
> assuming human likeness, hiding their reptilian form. Simultaneously
> **the government has given the team less than 24 hours to terminate this alien force before launching an air strike with tactical nukes to
> completely sterilize the area**. Lambert and his team now must battle
> this alien military force as the clock ticks and a squadron carrying
> certain death approaches.

In the sequel from 2002, the alien's mate arrives on Earth seeking revenge. Again, from the imdb summary:

> In the not too distant future a new team of specially trained
> government soldiers called an Interception Team contend with the
> latest hostile alien encounter. When an alien scout ship crashes in
> eastern Russia, Sean Lambert and his elite force are dispatched to
> investigate. They come face-to-face with a seemingly invincible
> seven-foot tall, shape shifting foe **hell-bent on blowing up a Russian
> nuclear power plant** in an effort to destroy mankind through a nuclear
> winter. The stakes become personal when the alien discovers it was
> Lambert who killed its mate four years ago (Interceptor Force). A
> major battle ensues as the Interceptor Team look to save the Earth
> from alien annihilation.

The alien is impervious to all the weapons used on it, but is eventually defeated when it dissolves in a pool of toxic liquid.

Comment: Glad to help @Joe  Can you click the checkmark to accept my answer? Then other people will be able to see that the question has been answered. Thanks!

Comment: Having read the IMDB links, I feel tempted to edit the first sentence to say "... even-lower-budget sequel ..." !